# Mraid js with svelte build application

Tags: javascript, html, ads, banner-ads, mraid

This is the first time I've encountered mraid technology and banner ads. There was a description in the technical Specification that you can use any tool and scripts can be put in a separate file, so I made a game on Svelte. I don't know how I can use mraid together with svelte and whether they can be used with each other at all. It also said the following:

> Just plain good old html/javascript with any common JS libraries of
> your choice - if your playable is more like a mini-website (poll,
> video playing in the frame, etc)
>
> Some tips for building playable: ·         You will usually host
> assets on your own CDN. Make sure it is easy to link to all your
> assets (images, sounds, etc) via absolute urls in the final version of
> your playable.  ·         You will usually give the ad network "a tag"
> (=body content of your main html file). Try to keep your index.html
> file small, keep as much logic as possible in your JS file.  ·
> Deploy your game to CDN. Copy-paste your "game tag" (game index.html
> body content) into test-a-tag.com as early as practical to test that
> all works fine.

And after I threw off the wrong version, I was sent the following:

> I see that one of the zip files is for index.html - a web page. We
> don’t generally support that kind of playable and it would be MUCH
> better and appreciated if you could simply send us an Mraid tag
> containing the creative and tracking.

An example of how I tried to connect:

```
<script src="mraid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initMraid() {
        if (!isMraidAvailable()) {
            showAd();
            return;
        }

        if (mraid.getState() === "loading") {
            mraid.addEventListener("ready", onReady);
        }
        else {
            console.log("mraid is ready");
            onReady();
        }
    }

    function onReady() {
        console.log("onReady");
        if (mraid.isViewable()) {
            setupAd();
        } else {
            mraid.addEventListener("viewableChange", onDisplayed);
        }
    }

    function onDisplayed(viewable) {
        console.log("onDisplayed: " + viewable);
        if (viewable) {
            mraid.removeEventListener("viewableChange", onDisplayed);
            setupAd();
        }
    }

    function setupAd() {
        mraid.setOrientationProperties({
            allowOrientationChange: false,
            forceOrientation: "portrait"
        });
        showAd();
    }

    function isMraidAvailable() {
        return typeof mraid !== "undefined";
    }

    function showAd() {
        console.log("showAd");
        if (isMraidAvailable()) {
           //start app
        }
    }

    function closeAd() {
        console.log("closeAd");
        if (isMraidAvailable()) {
            mraid.close();
        }
    }

</script>

<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    initMraid();
</script>
<script type="module" crossorigin src="/assets/index.dcdba288.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/index.c4d8ed5c.css">
```

And also please tell me how to get this mraid tag

Answer (score 0):

I just came across [this](https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/general/mraid-specifications-guidelines/) IronSource documentation that has a brief explanation of the mraid tag.
It appears that it's just basic html tags, but *without* wrapping it in `<html></html>`

*wrong

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://example.com">
    <img src="http://example.com/images/image.jpg">
  </a>
</body>
</html>
```

*right

```
 <a href="http://example.com">
 <img src="http://example.com/images/image.jpg"> </a>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33538329)